# same name input form change value beform submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have the form:

```
<form action="xxx">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="dataType" value="newsite" checked> newsite
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="dataType" value="newsiteAndOtherInfo"> newsiteAndOtherInfo
  </label>
  <div id="newsite">  
    <input name="site" value="1"/>
  </div>
  <div id="newsiteAndOtherInfo" style="display:none">
    <input name="site" value="2"/>
    <input name="OtherInfo" />
    ......
  </input>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "newsite") {
        $("#newsiteAndOtherInfo").hide();
        $("#newsite").show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "newsiteAndOtherInfo") {
        $("#newsite").hide();
        $("#newsiteAndOtherInfo").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

when submit, the form data would be:

> site: 1,2

While I only want the visible input value to be pass to server.

I know `$.ajax` can do it easily. Such as

```
var site = $("[name=site]:visible").val();
var data = {"site":site};
$.ajax({
  url:"xxx",
  type: 'post',
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

But If I use form submit synchronously, change value not work.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
      formdata(this);
      return true;
    });
});

function formdata(form) {
    var site = $(form).find("[name=site]:hidden").val();
    form.site.value = site;  // not work
}
```

Ｉ suppose there must be method changing data before submit but just can't find it.

---

[EDIT]

As my question is not clear, add some supplement here.

In fact, the two div are two kinds of form data, some of the input are with same field.

Comment: first i've saw the two inputs has the same name, so will be a mistake between when you try to change the value

Comment: Why not use radio buttons for that?

Comment: Just use radio buttons

Comment: If you still want to stick to your HTML you can differentiate the two inputs by ID or by class and then get the value.I agree with all comments above.

Comment: Now I've edit my question to make it clear.